# Ces deux phrases ci-dessous sont-elles grammaticalement correctes ? naturelles ?

Tags: grammaire

Les deux phrases ci-dessous sont-elles grammaticalement correctes ? naturelles ?

1. "Merci de me contacter si vous avez mon certificat de résidence."
2. "Je souhaite que ma camarade éteint les lumières et observe le silence entre 24h et 7h du matin pour le sommeil profond."

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Première demande :

> Merci de me contacter si vous avez mon certificat de résidence.

C’est correct et habituel dans le langage courant. Cette phrase peut être améliorée en ajoutant une formulation plus complète :

> Merci de **bien vouloir** me contacter si vous avez mon certificat de résidence.

Deuxième demande ;

> Je souhaite que ma camarade éteint les lumières et observe le silence entre 24h et 7h du matin pour le sommeil profond.

Pour celle-ci il manque le subjonctif (pour éteindre - observe est aussi du subjonctif ) (c’est un des cas où il faut l’utiliser).. la fin n’est pas tout à fait correcte : il faut être plus précis sur ce que tu recherche. On parle plutôt de 0h ou minuit

> Je souhaite que ma camarade **éteigne** les lumières et observe le silence entre **minuit** et 7h du matin pour **ne pas perturber ma période de** sommeil profond.

Note : il y a peut-être mieux pour la fin de la deuxième phrase.
Note 2 : la prochaine fois, fais une demande par phrase.